# Copy row in a form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, html-table

I'm new to JS and I've a problem that I can't solve. I have a dynamic table that is adding rows based on onclick events. The problem is that I would like to have all the rows created in another input field on the same page by clicking a button at the end of the table.
Anyone can help me, please?
Here you can find the code of the table:

```
<table id="orderedProductsTbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="h2" style="padding-top:30px;">Esperienze</td>
            <td class="h1" height="80" width="50px" align="right"></td>
            <td height="80" width="50px" class="titlerow" align="left"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="orderedProductsTblBody">                        
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td>Totale</td>
            <td align="right">€</td>
            <td class="totalCol" align="center"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And the form:

```
<fieldset class="pure-group" style="">
  <label for="name">Nome: </label>
  <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="What your Mom calls you" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group">
  <label for="surname">Cognome: </label>
  <input id="surname" name="surname" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group">
  <label for="email"><em>Your</em> Email Address:</label>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value=""
  required placeholder="your.name@email.com"/>
  <span id="email-invalid" style="visibility:hidden">
    Must be a valid email address</span>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group">
  <label for="date">Data:</label>
  <input id="date" name="date" type="text"/>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group">
  <label for="time">Ora:</label>
  <input id="time" name="time" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group">
  <label for="pax">Numero di Persone: </label>
  <input id="pax" name="pax" />
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="pure-group">
  <label for="message">Esperienze: </label>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
</fieldset>
 </div>
 <button class="boxh">INVIA</button>
</form>
```

And the JS ruling the table:

```
  var shoppingCart = [];

    //this function manipulates DOM and displays content of our shopping cart
    function displayShoppingCart(){
        var orderedProductsTblBody=document.getElementById("orderedProductsTblBody");
        //ensure we delete all previously added rows from ordered products table
        while(orderedProductsTblBody.rows.length>0) {
            orderedProductsTblBody.deleteRow(0);
        }

        //variable to hold total price of shopping cart
        var cart_total_price=0;
        //iterate over array of objects
        for(var product in shoppingCart){
            //add new row      
            var row=orderedProductsTblBody.insertRow();
            //add button
            var removeRow=document.createElement("Button");
            //add button2
            var addproduct=document.createElement("Button");
            //set up button
            removeRow.innerHTML= "X"; 
            removeRow.setAttribute("onClick", "deleteRow(this)");
            removeRow.className = "btad";  
            //set up button2
            addproduct.innerHTML= "PRENOTA";
            addproduct.className = "btad1";               
            //create four cells for product properties 
            var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
            var cellDescription = row.insertCell(1);
            var cellPrice = row.insertCell(2);
            var cellDelete = row.insertCell(3);
            var cellAdd =row.insertCell(4);
            cellName.className = 'copyname';
            cellPrice.className = 'rowDataSd';
            cellPrice.align="center";
            cellDescription.align ="right";
            cellDelete.align="right";
            cellName.height="40";
            cellPrice.height="40";
            cellDescription.height="40";
            cellDelete.height="40"
            cellAdd.height="40"
            //fill cells with values from current product object of our array
            cellName.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Name;
            cellDescription.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Description;
            cellPrice.innerHTML = shoppingCart[product].Price;
            cellDelete.appendChild( removeRow );
            cellAdd.appendChild(addproduct);
            cart_total_price+=shoppingCart[product].Price;
        }

    function AddtoCart(name,description,price){
       //Below we create JavaScript Object that will hold the properties you have mentioned:    Name,Description and Price
       var singleProduct = {};
       //Fill the product object with data
       singleProduct.Name=name;
       singleProduct.Description=description;
       singleProduct.Price=price;
       //Add newly created product to our shopping cart 
       shoppingCart.push(singleProduct);
       //call display function to show on screen
       displayShoppingCart();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the addproduct is the button that will add the row to the form, you need to add this on the js code.

```
`addproduct.setAttribute("onClick", "AddRowToForm(this)");`
```

if you are using jquery this function should work

```
function AddRowToForm(row){
    // get the values from the table
    var name = $("#"+row).find('td').eq(0).html(); 
    // "eq(0)" is the numer of the column of the table
    var surname = $("#"+row).find('td').eq(1).html();
    var email= $("#"+row).find('td').eq(2).html();
    var date = $("#"+row).find('td').eq(3).html();
    var time = $("#"+row).find('td').eq(4).html();
    var pax = $("#"+row).find('td').eq(5).html();
    var message = $("#"+id).find('td').eq(6).html();
    // insert values to the Form
    $("#name").val(name);
    $("#surname").val(surname);
    $("#email").val(email);
    $("#date").val(date);
    $("#time").val(time);
    $("#pax").val(pax);
    $("#message").val(message);
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately it seems that nothing happens... If I have to retrieve only the cellAdd by ClassName (addproduct.className = "btad1"; ) which is the first one in the table, to the form field (#message) would be easier? Thank you again for your time!